# How to set XMLTYPE as type in EA architect in diagramm for Oracle database?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a problem to set `XMLTYPE` as type in column for Oracle database.

How can i do that?

This is a screen with my table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to `Project/Settings/Database Datatypes`
- Select Oracle from the drop down
- Enter `XMLTYPE` in Datatype and press save

[image]